# What are the downsides of making a class Serializable?

Tags: java, scala, serialization

Want to deep copy objects in Java / Scala. After doing some research, it seems that Serialization is the most popular way do it. However, that also means making the classes *Serializable*.

What, if any, are the downsides of making a class Serializable in Java / Scala?

Comment: One downside is that you actually should* ensure that it **is** serializable... aka, not having recurring pointers.

Comment: See *Effective Java, Item 74: Implement Serializable judiciously*

Comment: It's an interesting question. But for StackOverflow this basic/general questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

One potential downside is that all of your class members will also need to be serializable.  In otherwords, you will not be able to use any non-serializable data types for your class members.

For example, in APEX (Java for Salesforce), the DOM.Document class is not serializable, so it is not possible to make a serializable class that has a member of type DOM.Document.

You may be able to overcome this by using the 'transient' keyword, but that also has drawbacks.